# Examine change over the years

Tags: time-series, correlation

Let's assume I want to test whether the top ten finishers in a specific sports become lighter over a ten-year period. With top ten finishers for each year, I have a similar number of datapoints per year.

I was thinking of simply doing a pearson correlation between year of race and athlete weight. Is this an appropriate way to go about this or is there something else I could/should look into?

Comment: Plot the data (ten points per year, shown individually, as a time series plot).  What do you learn?

Comment: @whuber I've essentially created a scatterplot with year on the x-axis and weight on the y-axis. I hope I am right in assuming that this would then correspond to a time series plot. Adding a regression line, it looks like a negative association, which also fits with the negative correlation coefficient I obtained in the statistical analyses.

Comment: That's a good start.  If the regression line is a good summary of the trend in the data, you could simply test whether the correlation coefficient is zero (versus the alternative that it is nonzero).  The remarks about independence or lack of it in other comments and answers might not be of concern, because you only need that the *variations* in the weights relative to the fitted line be uncorrelated between any two years. But if you could track individual finishers over time you might have greater power to learn about changes in the weights of the winners over time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you also want to do a statistical test and not just a descriptive statistic, this would violate the assumption that observations need to be independent. In your case the weight of each athlete in subsequent years would be dependent, colloquially said because the weight in one year is more likely to be closer to the weight the year before than completely different. This is how spurious correlations such as the one between the number of storks and births of babies occur - just because the number of storks depends on the number of storks the year before (by birth rate of storks) and the number of babies depends on the number of babies the year before (by all the more or less constant factors which keep the birth rate of babies quite stable).

Long story short: You would need a model which takes this dependency into account, for instance a multilevel model for repeated measures (which has the additional benefit that you do not need to calculate means by year, which would additionally reduce your power to find effects, but you can use all your data points).

Comment: Many thanks for you response! I fully appreciate the problem of partially repeat observations as described in your response. If there were no repeat data, however, would a correlation be an appropriate approach despite a similar number of observations per year?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, exactly. The original question as I understood was having 10 athletes, with three measurements each for a couple of years. What is the new suggestion compared to that?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's my fault for not being sufficiently clear. What I mean is the 10 athletes with top-10 classifications. If this were 10 different athletes coming into the top 10 each year (dropped the assumption of more than one race, as it makes it unnecessarily complicated I think), i.e. there are no problems with repeat data, would a correlation be an appropriate approach despite a similar number of observations per year?

Comment: After whuber's comment above I am not so sure about this dependency issue anymore and I might delete my answer. Because what you want to do is basically a trend line, which is ok to do with correlations - it is not as in my example that you correlate two variables over time. However, I do not see through it clearly enough right now so I keep the answer for now. Let me also say a couple of partly related things:

Comment: 1) You keep saying "despite similar number of observations per year" - there is no such rule about numbers of obs., except that you should look for outliers and maybe years in between with not much data.
2) Your solution would get rid of the dependencies (which, again, might be no issue) but I am not sure whether this would be realistic (it assumes that no one will ever get >= 2 top 10 performances, and excluding data just to meet this might also be bad). And 3), I would try to not lump the data points into years, but keep them at the actual date the event happened to improve estimation.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful inputs. RE 1): I keep pointing this out because the occurrences will not be normally distributed as there are similar numbers per year. I was wondering whether this violates the assumption of normally distributed data. Although, the residuals may still be normally distributed. I'd be interested in  hearing your thoughts on this. RE 2) and your comment before that: Am I right in assuming you'd still correlate weight by year/date but because of one variable being time-related this is more of a trend-line situation?

Comment: Perhaps a useful approach might be to run an analysis using all data and double check the results with a second analysis that only includes each athlete once (e.g. first time in the top ten).

Comment: 1) According to my quick search, cross validated seems to fight quite a bit whether or not normality of data is important for pearson correlation or not and I do not think I can add anything meaningful about this. Intuitively, in your case I would not worry about it too much. Your variables are not bounded, they seem to be linearly related, it is just that you happen to only be able to collect ten data points per year. Personally, I would be more afraid of outliers at the ends of your observation period. 2) Yes, where date should be better than year.

Comment: 3-ish) Well, in general I like trying different things and see how they influence results. However, if they come out differently, what do you do? And which one do you trust? They might even slightly change the research question so it is not clear that analyses are equal considering your goal. I would rather advise to do more research and decide for a strategy that can handle dependency (if necessary at all).